# How to load a video permanently into a project

Tags: vb.net

If you add a picture into a project, then remove the picture from it's original source, the picture is still in the project even though it doesn't exist in its original location.

I want to do the same thing with a video.

How can I add a video to a project in such a way that it can be deleted from its original location and it will still exist in the project?

Comment: I want a gold plated rolls royce but it ain't gonna happen without me putting some effort in.

Comment: This isnt a well pose question Herry - Have a look here [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is dynamic ressources and not static(local) ones. You can input them by drag&drop into your **solution explorer** or if you double click on your project in the solution explorer the project properties open - there you have a tab called **ressources** where you can input any kind of ressources.

If you dont know how to play a movie within a VB Form - [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLQtUxoX0zw&index=7&list=PL86A8013B8782A7AD) is a tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: Thanks GrindelOh. Solved.

Comment: @HerryMarkowitz It seems you haven't accepted any answer for your questions while you have found some of them useful. Please click on check mark near the answer that you found most useful to accept it. While you can accept only one answer, you can vote for as many answers as you find helpful :)